# how to unit test a component which has @Input variables in angular7?

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

I have an `angular` component which has some `Input()` variables in which is coming from `parent` component like this

`componet.ts`

```
  @Input() transactions: any[] = [];
  @Input() total: number = 0;
  @Input() cash: number = 0;
  @Input() card: number = 0;
  @Input() cheque: number = 0;


  ngOnInit() {
   this.paidToDate = (this.card || 0) + (this.cash || 0) + (this.cheque || 0);
  }
```

And when i try to run unit test for this component which has only basic unit test of component `creation` like this

`component.spec.ts`

```
describe('EstimateTotalComponent', () => {
let component: EstimateTotalComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<EstimateTotalComponent>;

 beforeEach(async(() => {
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [ 
    EstimateTotalComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    CheckboxModule,
    DropdownModule,
    TableModule,
    AutoCompleteModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    SharedModule,
    RouterTestingModule,
    CookieModule.forRoot(),
    ToastrModule.forRoot(),
    NgxMaskModule.forRoot(),
    TabViewModule,
    LoadingBarHttpClientModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  providers: [
    HTTPService,
    HelperService,
    DateService,
    ValidationService,
    CookieService,
    ToastrService,
    SocketService,
    CalculationService,
    DataService,
    DialogService
   ],
   schemas : [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
 })
  .compileComponents();
}));

 beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(EstimateTotalComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  component.transactions = [];
  component.total = 0;
  component.cash = 0;
  component.card = 0;
  component.cheque = 0;
  fixture.detectChanges();
});

it(UNIT_TEST.ComponentCreated, () => {
 expect(component).toBeTruthy();
});
```

But it throws an error like this.

How can i get rid of this error?

[image]

Comment: Did you get any solution  ? BTW, since you have already initialized the value `@Input() total: number = 0;` you should not get an error for `component.total`. I think you are using `.total` on some other object in component. Can you share your component code so that I can investigate the issue ?

Comment: i fount the issue. And yes that's correct. i am using `.total` on some places. So i provided those values also so now it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define all `@Inpu`t variables in `beforeEach`

```
beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(EstimateTotalComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  component.total=0;
  component.cash = 0;
  component.card = 0;
  component.cheque = 0;
  fixture.detectChanges();
});
```

Comment: it's still giving an error. Please see updated post. I have included the update test file code. I initialized all `input` variables but still it's giving the same error

Comment: please share your oninit method

Comment: i added `ngOnInit` method. you can check updated post

Comment: add this inside testconfigurationModule `schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]`

Comment: should i import `testconfigurationModule ` ?

Comment: what should i import ?

Comment: add new property inside TestBed.configureTestingModule

Comment: sorry I meant configureTestingModule  instead of testconfigurationModule

Comment: please see my updated post. I have included what you said